# Cryptic Databasenames for PostgreSQL using Spring Boot Maven

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, maven

On my PC I get the following error starting my Spring-Boot Server:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Datenbank ╗Test½ existiert nicht (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)`

(The first part is german and translates to "The Database does not exist")

In pgAdmin I created the Database "Test" and in my Application Properties I call the Database with
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test`

I think it may be an issue with encoding as it works on my laptop but I can not figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason Peter translates double quotes in error messages as `»` and `«`, so the English `"Test"` will become `»Test«`.

Now the `client_encoding` in your database session does not match your terminal's encoding, so the quotes look wrong.

I assume that you are on Windows, where the "shell" uses a different encoding than the rest of the system. Things will probably improve if you run the following in your `cmd` before starting your program:

```
chcp 1252
```

At any rate, you need not worry about this.

Comment: Thanks, I found the Problem at another point in the code but your answer is definitely appreciated.